# How to retrieve the PostgreSQL's data that was deleted accidentally?

Tags: postgresql, restore

I deleted some data from PostgreSQL's one table's carelessly.

Please give me some advice, How can I retrieve it.

I want to use pg_dirtyread extension, but my server is Windows Server 2019, I don't know how to install the extension.

The extension's Github is https://github.com/df7cb/pg_dirtyread.

Please Help Me.

Thanks very much.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use pg\_dirtyread on windows server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68142371/how-to-use-pg-dirtyread-on-windows-server)

Comment: Please do not repost the same question with slightly different title. If you wish to revise the question just update it.

Comment: ok, you are right. too impatient to do it. Not again.